# Trying to run hadoop 2.7.1; localhost refused to connect

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to use hadoop (2.7.1) for the first time using cygwin on win 8. I followed the configuration and i think every thing is well. However when i issue sbin/start-all.sh, i get the following error

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Also when i try to use the browser and issue http://localhost:50030/ or http://localhost:50070/ i get the following message

```
This site can’t be reached 
localhost refused to connect.
```

How can I get my computer to stop refusing the connection? I don't know much about networking or servers. Thanks in advance

Comment: look at the log also try `netstat -a` to see if it is actually listenning

Comment: Neither 50030 nor 50070 is listening... what should i do

Comment: Have to check your log. You want to look for exception and start from there